# How to add Keyboard language on AndroidTV emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, android-tv

I'm developing AndroidTV application. And I need to input characters from another language into `EditText` (in my case - Russian). Is there any way I can do it?

Simply typing Russian doesn't make any effect. I also tried via `adb input text`, but as text contains Russian characters it gets killed.

```
generic_x86:/ # whoami                                                                                                                     
root
generic_x86:/ # input text 'пвыа'                                                                                                          
Killed 
137|generic_x86:/ # input text 'sdf'                                                                                                       
generic_x86:/ #
```

I also didn't find a way to add a new keyboard layout, I googled for it, but no luck so far.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use api 28 base emulator.

Settings -> Device preference -> Keyboard -> Gboard Settings -> Language -> Replace English with your language